# Translating Matlab code with arrays into Fortran

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to translate Matlab code into Fortran code.  I am currently struggling with data type array translation.

The Matlab/GNU Octave code example is as follows

```
function test1

clc;
close all;
start= 5;

function out = function1(start)
myarray = struct(...
    'list1', {'A', 'Cc', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'}, ...
    'list2', {1, 2,  3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8},...
    'list3', {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2});

function list1 = function2(list2)
    done = false;
    ra = randi([1 numel(myarray)], 1, 1);
    list1 = myarray(ra);
    if list1.list1 == 'E'
        list1.list1 = round(randn(1,1) * 5);
    end
end

x = {}; 
y = [];
list2 = 0;    

    list1 = function2(list2);
    list2 = list2 + list1.list3;

    x = [x, list1.list1];
    y = [y, list2];
  out = struct('x', {x}, 'y', {y});
end
disp(function1(2));
end
```

The output of Octave is :

```
scalar structure containing the fields:
x =
{
  [1,1] = G
}
y =  2
```

My Fortran attempt has bugs that I am struggling with.  The problem deals with my handling of arrays and the way Matlab code is written.

```
function function1(start) result(out1)

implicit none

 type array
  character list1
  integer   list2, list3
 end type array

 type(array), dimension(8) :: myarray
               integer :: start;
               integer :: out1;

    character, dimension(8,1), allocatable ::x
    character, dimension(1,8), allocatable ::y

  myarray=[array('A',1,3), array('C',2,3), array('B',3,3), & 
           array('E',4,3), array('F',4,3), array('G',5,3), & 
           array('H',6,3), array('I',5,3)]


    deallocate(x);                              !<- in matlab x={}
    deallocate(y);                              !<- in matlab y=[]
    deallocate(list2);                          !<- in matlab list2 = 0;    

      list1 = function2(list2);
      list2 = list2 + list1%list3;

      x = [x, list1%list1];              !<- this line not translated
      y = [y, list2];                    !<- this line not translated
   out1 = struct('x', {x}, 'y', {y});   !<- this line not translated


   contains

    function function2(list2) result(list1)

    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: list2;             ! input
    integer :: list1;                         ! output  
    logical :: done;  
    integer, dimension(1,1) :: ra;
    real    :: rnd1;
    integer :: test;

     done = .FALSE.
     call random_number(rnd1);
     ra = nint(rnd1*size(myarray));  
     list1=myarray(ra); 

     if (list1%list1 .EQV. 'E') then   
       call random_number(rnd1);
       list1%list1 = nint(rnd1*5);     
     end if

    end function function2

end function function1

program test1

 use iso_fortran_env
 implicit none

  integer                 :: start, xout;
  integer                 :: function1;

 start =5;
 xout=function1(2);
 print*, "my output is ", xout;
end program test1
```

Usually Matlab does not define beforehand the variable for array type.  This is not the case for Fortran.  I marked the problematic lines of code.  They all share the common ground which is passing an array value to another variable or passing value to a variable.  Any hints and suggestions?

The error code I am getting is

```
  gfortran  -Ofast -Wall -o "test1" "test1.f90"  
  test1.f90:22:20:
  deallocate(list2);                          !<- in matlab list2 = 0;
                1
  Error: Allocate-object at (1) is not a nonprocedure pointer nor an    allocatable variable
  test1.f90:25:30:
     list2 = list2 + list1%list3;
                          1
   Error: Symbol ‘list1’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
   test1.f90:27:22:
     x = [x, list1%list1];              !<- this line not translated
                  1
   Error: Symbol ‘list1’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
   test1.f90:29:25:
   out1 = struct('x', {x}, 'y', {y});   !<- this line not translated
                     1
   Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
   test1.f90:48:19:
      if (list1%list1 .EQV. 'E') then
               1
   Error: Unexpected ‘%’ for nonderived-type variable ‘list1’ at (1)
   test1.f90:50:17:
        list1%list1 = nint(rnd1*5);
             1
   Error: Unexpected ‘%’ for nonderived-type variable ‘list1’ at (1)
   test1.f90:51:14:
        end if
          1
   Error: Expecting END FUNCTION statement at (1)
   test1.f90:24:13:
     list1 = function2(list2);
         1
   Error: Symbol ‘list1’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
   test1.f90:24:31:
     list1 = function2(list2);
                           1
   Error: Symbol ‘list2’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
   test1.f90:12:46:
   character, dimension(8,1), allocatable ::x
                                          1
   Error: Allocatable array ‘x’ at (1) must have a deferred shape or     assumed rank
   test1.f90:13:46:
   character, dimension(1,8), allocatable ::y
                                          1
   Error: Allocatable array ‘y’ at (1) must have a deferred shape or assumed rank
   test1.f90:47:23:
      list1=myarray(ra);
                   1
 Error: Array index at (1) is an array of rank 2
 Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Pkease use tag forrran for all Fortran questions. You will get much more attention. Is your code complete? It is full of ssyntax errors. Foremost, the declaration of the derived tyoe is not finished with `end type`. Many ofyour variables are not declared. You *must* use IMPLICIT NONE and you must show it in the code sample. It really seems your xode is not a complete [mcve].

Comment: @VladimirF, the derived type definition `array` does have an `end type`, and there isn't another one.

Comment: @francescalus OK, the indentation is very confusing. Still I think the code is incomplete. The compiler complains about an implicit type where there is no implicit statement in sight. The whole syntax is strange with superfluous semicolons and the usage of `%` in the code is just beyond my comprehension.

Comment: @VladimirF, oh yes, there are other problems.  As you say, `implicit none` would point to some of the errors.  But to the questioner: I suspect you intend `myarray(list1)%...` rather than `list1%...`.